# How to declare secondary or non-unique index in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

It seems like mysql only provides four kinds of indexes, which are primary, unique, key, fulltext and spatial. But I was wondering how to declare index for those of columns which are not unique but often gets indexed? Because my database server is hitting a bottleneck, and I'd like to create index for columns that are frequently indexed.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Leave out the `UNIQUE` modifier and it's a non-unique index.

Comment: `key` and `index` are one and the same. you're talking about different attributes of indexes. The rule of thumb for adding indexes is that any field(s) used in a `where`, `join`, `order by`, or `group by` should be indexed. e.g. anywhere a field is used in a "decision"-type context.

Comment: so key is non-unique index?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Please distinguish between "key" and "index".

The former is a logical concept (restricts, and therefore changes the meaning of data) and the later is physical (doesn't change the meaning, but can change the performance)<sup>1</sup>.

Let's get the basic concepts straight:

- A "superkey" is any set of attributes that, taken together, are unique.
- A "candidate key" (or just "key") is minimal superkey - if you take any attribute away from it, it is no longer unique.
- All keys are logically equivalent, but we pick one of them as "primary key" for practical<sup>2</sup> and historical reasons, the rest are called "alternate keys".
- In the database, you declare primary key using PRIMARY KEY constraint, and alternate key using UNIQUE constraint on NOT NULL fields.
- Most DBMSes (MySQL is no exception) will automatically create indexes underneath keys. Nonetheless, they are still separate concepts and some DBMSes will actually allow you to have a key without index.

Unfortunately, MySQL has royally messed-up the terminology:

- MySQL uses **column** constraint KEY as a synonym for PRIMARY KEY.
- MySQL uses **table** constraint KEY for index, **not** key, same if you were to use CREATE INDEX statement.

So for example, both...

```
CREATE TABLE T (
  A INT PRIMARY KEY,
  B INT
);

CREATE INDEX T_IE1 ON T (B);
```

...and...

```
CREATE TABLE T (
  A INT KEY,
  B INT,
  KEY (B)
);
```

...mean the same thing: primary key on A (with unique/clustering index on A) and non-unique index on B.

---

*<sup>1</sup> Unique index is an oddball here - it straddles both worlds a little bit. But let's leave that discussion for another time...*

*<sup>2</sup> For example, InnoDB [clusters](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes/) the table on primary key.*

Comment: In the first example, you declare A as primary key and B as unique index whereas you declare both A and B as Key. I could see how they are equivalent. But my question is, how do I declare a non-unique column that gets accessed frequently as an index in mysql? Like start_time of meetings - it could totally be the same other meetings, but we will often use it in where/order by/group by clause.

Comment: @user3216886 _"B as unique index"_ - no I don't, please reread the answer. _"But my question is, how do I declare a non-unique column that gets accessed frequently as an index in mysql?"_ by using table-level (not column-level) KEY or CREATE INDEX, as shown in the answer.

Comment: Oh I see - I guess everything I've been doing is on table level. So 'Key' at table-level acts like an index. How do we distinguish what are table-level and what are column-level? In my GUI app, I simply right-click on the desired column and pick an option under 'create index'. A is PRIMARY KEY in first example but is KEY is second example, yet they are both primary key, meaning they are column-level. But I don't quite see how to differentiate key creation at column-level vs table-level.

Comment: @user3216886 `A INT KEY` is column-level. `KEY (B)` is table-level. The same keyword is used, but they mean a different thing.

Comment: Wow. I did not know that. Just to ensure that I got it right, `A INT KEY` makes `A` a primary key as well as index, while `KEY (B)` makes it a non-unique index?

Comment: @AttitudeMonger Yup. Strange quirk of this particular DBMS.

Comment: Ah, got it. So by non-unique index I assume that sorts would be very fast, except that the values can be non-unique, right? Which also means I can use `KEY (B)` multiple times to declare non-unique index on multiple columns?

Comment: @AttitudeMonger Indexes are not just for sorting - please take a look at http://use-the-index-luke.com. And yes, you can create multiple non-unique indexes, but you can also create multiple unique indexes (if that makes sens for your data, of course).

Comment: Umm yes, not only for sorting but also for searching by `where` clause.